# Wildcard in blob ends with path - ADF trigger blob storage event

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a blob structure like this:

```
> data/
>     folder1/
>            dirA/
>            dirB/
>            dirC/
>                 file1.csv
>                 file2.csv
>                 file3.csv
>     dir2/
>            dirA/
>            dirB/
>            dirC/
>                 file1.csv
>                 file2.csv
>                 file3.csv
>     source3/
>            dirA/
>            dirB/
>            dirC/
>                 file1.csv
>                 file2.csv
>                 file3.csv
```

I want to trigger the blob storage event when any csv file is uploaded to source3/dirC only.
[image]

The problem is adf doesnt support wildcard path here. I want something like this:

**Blob_path_ends_with:** `any_dir(exclude folder1 include dir2,source3)/dirC/*.csv (any csv file in dirC in any main directory)`

**So I want to ignore any csv uploads in the folder1 but trigger event on upload of files in dir2 and source3.**

Comment: As per the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-event-trigger?tabs=data-factory#create-a-trigger-with-ui) in ADF, currently storage event triggers do not support wild card paths. see this https://i.imgur.com/ZIjNANi.png.

Comment: So, if you want use only storage event triggers on this case, trigger on every file on that container and then using trigger filePath parameter filter the files with your required folders in pipeline.

Comment: Can u plz help me understand what this really means:

Blob path begins with and ends with are the only pattern matching allowed in Storage Event Trigger. Other types of wildcard matching aren't supported for the trigger type

It either supports wildcard or doesnt. What does it mean by "Blob path begins with and ends with are the only pattern matching"

Comment: It means they do not support wild card matching like `*/folder/folder1`, they only support pattern matching with strings like if we blob name starts with as `input/`, it will give all files which have paths starting with `input` but do not support the wild card matching. go through these examples for better understanding https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-event-trigger?tabs=data-factory#examples-of-storage-event-triggers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing the folder structure to

> data
> source1
> dirA
> dirB
> source2
> dirA
> dirB
> source3
> dirA
> dirB
> So all the files that I want to trigger the pipeline are always in **source3/dirB**
> and using BlobPathStartsWith as **data/source3/dirB** and BlobPathEndsWith **.csv**

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Rakesh Govindula, path **begins with** and **ends with** are the only pattern matching **allowed in Storage Event Trigger**. Other types of wildcard matching aren't supported for the trigger type.

However you can workaround this with a logic app as follows:
[image: Architecture]

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create an Event Grid System Topic ([Documentaion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/create-view-manage-system-topics#create-a-system-topic))
   Select *Storage Accounts (Blob & GPv2)* for topic type. You can choose any name for the topic.
2. Create a Logic app with http trigger type
   Paste the following [Event Grid Event Schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema-blob-storage?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json&tabs=event-grid-event-schema#microsoftstorageblobcreated-event) to the Logic App's http trigger's *Request Body JSON Schema* field:

   ```
   [{
     "topic": "/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/Storage/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/my-storage-account",
     "subject": "/blobServices/default/containers/test-container/blobs/new-file.txt",
     "eventType": "Microsoft.Storage.BlobCreated",
     "eventTime": "2017-06-26T18:41:00.9584103Z",
     "id": "831e1650-001e-001b-66ab-eeb76e069631",
     "data": {
       "api": "PutBlockList",
       "clientRequestId": "6d79dbfb-0e37-4fc4-981f-442c9ca65760",
       "requestId": "831e1650-001e-001b-66ab-eeb76e000000",
       "eTag": "\"0x8D4BCC2E4835CD0\"",
       "contentType": "text/plain",
       "contentLength": 524288,
       "blobType": "BlockBlob",
       "url": "https://my-storage-account.blob.core.windows.net/testcontainer/new-file.txt",
       "sequencer": "00000000000004420000000000028963",
       "storageDiagnostics": {
         "batchId": "b68529f3-68cd-4744-baa4-3c0498ec19f0"
       }
     },
     "dataVersion": "",
     "metadataVersion": "1"
   }]
   ```

Save the logic app in designer and copy the content of the *HTTP POST URL* field. You will use it in the next.

3. Create an Event Subscription for the storage account ([Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingest-data-event-grid-manual#create-an-event-grid-subscription))
   Type in the System Topic Name field the event grid system topic you created in step 1. Select Webhook endpoint type and paste in the HTTP POST URL you coped in step 2.
   Once you are ready, you can test if the logic app is triggered if you upload a file to the storage. Go to the logic app and check the logs (raw outputs of the http trigger)
4. Add a condition step to the Logic app to stop the workflow if the http request's `body().data.url` parameter doesn't contains the path you need.
5. Add a Data Factory pipeline run step to the Logic App. ([Useful blogpost](https://gbamezai.medium.com/how-to-trigger-azure-data-factory-from-logic-apps-c3132aa24649))
   You can pass the path string as pipeline parameter from the http body: `body().data.url`

I hope you can follow the steps I described without screenshots.

Comment: Hi @Thomas Keul,

What does this really means:

 path begins with and ends with are the only pattern matching allowed in Storage Event Trigger. Other types of wildcard matching aren't supported

Does it means it allowes pattern matching liek this:

Starts with:  **/pathA/pathB
endswith: pathA/*.csv ?

If yes, this doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below workaround using ADF.

This my folder structure.

```
input
    source1
        dirC
    source2
        dirC
    source3
        dirC
            ##file uploading
```

Create two parameters for uploading file name and folder path.

and another parameter of array type and give your folder names that you want the file to be uploaded.

[image]

I have created the trigger like below for the container `input`

[image]

give the `@triggerBody().fileName` and `@triggerBody().folderPath` while creating trigger.

[image]

We will get the trigger file folder path value like `input/source3/dirC`. So, take this and check whether our folder names array values are exists or not in this string in if activity.

```
@contains(pipeline().parameters.folder_list, split(pipeline().parameters.folderpath, '/')[1])
```

[image]

Then inside True of if you can give your activities or if there are more activities you can use Execute pipeline activity.

**Sample copy activity:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi,

The source folders are dynamic, cant provide them as input to ppl.

Comment: `@triggerBody().folderPath` will give the source folder path on uploading the file to the container like this `input/source3/dirC`. The only thing we need to give is the required folder names in an array parameter so that we can check whether the uploaded file is from that particular folder or not.